# Can't assign character while iterating through char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, char

I need to convert a `char*` into `char* []` in order to pass it as a function argument.

The following dummy code gives a segmentation fault in the marked line, I can not figure out why.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f(char* const args[]){
    for( int i = 0; args[i] != (char*)NULL; ++i ){
        puts("x");
        printf("%s\n", args[i]);
    }
}

char** split(char* str, char tok){
    int len = strlen(str);
    printf("str: %s\n", str);
    printf("len: %d\n", len);
    int num = 2;
    char* it = str;
    for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i ){
        printf("it: %s\n", it);
        if( *it == tok ){
            *it = '\0'; // SEGFAULT
            num++;
        }
        it++;
    }
    printf("test\n");
    char** result = malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
    int j = 0;
    int save = 1;
    it = str;
    printf("it: %s\n", it);
    for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i ){
        if( *it == tok ){
            save = 1;
        }
        else if( save == 1 ){
            result[j++] = it;
            save = 0;
            printf("save: %d %p %s\n", j, it, it);
        }
    }
    result[j] = (char*)NULL;
    return result;
}

int main (){
    char *str = "my_program -f 1 -o out.txt";
    char** split_str = split(str, ' ');
    f(split_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pass a pointer to a string literal as the first argument. Then you iterate through said string literal and attempt to modify it. That is not allowed (it invokes *undefined behavior*) and you get a segmentation fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
char *str = "my_program -f 1 -o out.txt";
```

will create a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) and make `str` point to that string literal.

Your program is not allowed to modify a string literal. Any attempt to do so will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You are passing a pointer to the string literal to the function `split`, which then attempts to modify the string literal. Therefore, your program is invoking undefined behavior. This is probably the reason why you are getting a segmentation fault.

In order to fix this, you should not create a string literal. Instead, you should create a normal array which can be modified, for example like this:

```
char str[] = "my_program -f 1 -o out.txt";
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds reasonable. I'll check this out in the morning and will accept then.